# ejb 3.1, weblogic 12c, java 1.6 Jndi Lookup issue

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

```
I have problem in configuring JNDI lookup for ejb3.1 and weblogic 12c, jdk1.6

@Remote
public interface Bank{

    public String accounts();

}

@Stateless(name="BankSession")
public class BankSessionBean implements Bank{

    @Override
    public String accounts() {
                 ////////    }

ejb-jar.xml:   

    <enterprise-beans>
        <session>
            <display-name>BankSession</display-name>
            <ejb-name>BankSession</ejb-name>
            <business-remote>com.examples.Bank</business-remote>
            <ejb-class>com.examples.BankSessionBean</ejb-class>
            <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
            <transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>
        </session>
    <enterprise-beans>

weblogic-ejb-jar.xml:

 <weblogic-enterprise-bean>
    <ejb-name>BankSession</ejb-name>    
    <jndi-name>BankSession</jndi-name>
  </weblogic-enterprise-bean>


client code:
```

When i start using Jndi Look up using this syntax 
java:comp/env/ejb/BankSession

Its giving following error.

javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'java:comp/env/ejb/BankSession' didn't find subcontext.

Here ejbbean and client code runs on different jvm's.

Which Jndi look up should i use ?

1. java:comp/env/ejb/BankSession'
2. java:global/applicationName/moduleName/BankSession
3. java:module/BankSession
4. java:app/moduleName/BankSession

java:comp/env/ejb/BankSession is working fine with ejb 3.0 and oc4j server.

When i migrate to ejb3.1 and weblogic 12c, its not working.

I even tried without using weblogic deployment xml files. Same issue encountered.

How should i configure my Jndi here ? Please help as i am facing this issue since long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a lookup in the form of java:comp/env/... you need an EJB ref in the deployment descriptor of the component that does the lookup!
java:comp/env/... is always relative to the component that does the lookup.

A lookup name that is independent of the actual component that does the lookup and works from anywhere inside your application is 4.: java:app/moduleName/...

java:global/appName/... will fail if you decide to rename your ear file one day.
java:module/... only works inside a component that is part of the same module. 
So 4. is IMO the best alternative.

Comment: In which deployment descriptor do i need to add ejb ref for java:comp/env/ ? i have ejb ref already in application-client.xml file.  
 <ejb-ref>
        <ejb-ref-name>ejb/BankInquirySession</ejb-ref-name>
        <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
        <remote>com.examples.Bank</remote>
        <ejb-link>BankInquirySession</ejb-link>
     </ejb-ref>

Comment: What module/component is client of your bean (ejb, servlet, java client)? You need to add reference to that module/component. Application-client.xml is descriptor for thick Java client, so it is probably wrong one.

Comment: Ah ok. I overread that you did the lookup from an application client. If you do the lookup from an application client java:app/... might not work. Then I'd recommend to resolve the ejb-ref ejb/BankInquirySession to BankInquirySession and lookup java:comp/env/BankInquirySession.